# XSLT convert xml block under a specific node to xml-escaped content of that node

Tags: xslt, escaping, xslt-2.0, cdata

Any ideas of how the following problem can be solved would be highly appreciated.

INPUT:

```
<p>
    <div>
     Original<br/>This is the original <b>acid</b>, a hydroxy monocarboxylic <span class="hl1">acid</span>.
    </div>
</p>
```

Desired Output:

```
<p>
    <div>
     Original&lt;br/&gt;This is the original &lt;b&gt;acid&lt;/b&gt;, a hydroxy monocarboxylic &lt;span class=&quot;hl1&quot;&gt;acid&lt;/span&gt;.
    </div>
</p>
```

Attempt 1:

```
`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<!--The identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="/" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Attempt2:
as an alternative, I thought of placing the child elements' content into a CDATA wrapper.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<!--The identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="/" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But that does not give me what I want.
Anyone with a better idea? I'm using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? If that is Saxon 9, for instance Saxon 9.6, then I would simply set `version="3.0"` and use the http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize function. Older versions of Saxon have an extension to do the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm using saxon 9.1.0. I don't hink it is an option to switch to a newer version, as this is used at a number of places, and the effort to upgrade could be high!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using XSLT 3.0 [`serialize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize) as supported by Saxon 9.6 HE, PE and EE:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="serialize">
  <xsl:variable name="ser-params">
    <output:serialization-parameters xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
      <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes"/>
    </output:serialization-parameters>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="serialize(., $ser-params/*)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With older version of Saxon 9 you could use the extension function serialize, as shown in http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output name="inline" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="serialize">

  <xsl:value-of xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" select="saxon:serialize(., 'inline')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In my tests with Saxon 9.6 PE the functions supported with XSLT 3.0 are the XPath 3.0 functions. So the `serialize` and `parse-xml` functions are usable with 9.6 PE in a `version="3.0"` stylesheet module.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I wanted to say that with 9.6 HE the XPath 3.0 functions like `serialize` and `parse-xml` are supported in a stylesheet module with `version="3.0"`. As far as I tested that and http://saxon.markmail.org/message/fqoysgfiexzez74i?q=xpath+3.0+functions+from:%22Martin+Honnen%22&page=1#query:xpath%203.0%20functions%20from%3A%22Martin%20Honnen%22+page:1+mid:xqbep2367k2ucmxp+state:results confirmed it.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the clarification Martin. I'm only using PE and EE in oXygen and get a warning when trying to run a version 3.0 stylesheet with HE. Now it makes sense that the XPath 3.0 functions are actually available in HE.

Comment: Is there any option to do it without using external funtions. Could we define a custom function within the xslt that does this?

Comment: I don't see how the XPath 3.0 or Saxon's extension functions are external. And of course there is an extension provided in Saxon 9 before version 9.6 as pure XSLT/XPath does not provide that functionality of serialization as clean and easy way, unless you make sure you use two transformation steps and the result of each step is serialized. But there are pure though complex XSLT approaches of doing this, even in XSLT 1.0, see http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ for instance.

Comment: Yes you're right about there's nothing external about using the saxon function. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt should work if you change your `xsl:value-of` to an `xsl:copy-of` and tweak the `select`:

```
<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: while this works for this simple example, when I'm applying this in my real project where I'm chaining 2 xslt transformations, I end up having some processing instructions inserted and also end up having two levels of CDATA wrappers , as in: `<?javax.xml.transform.disable-output-escaping?><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]>`