# How to convert XML elements to text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest how to convert XML elements with their **name** and **content** as escaped text (i.e., `<a>` to `&lt;a&gt;`).

**XML:**

```
<article>
      <a>
           <b>a<c>a</c>aa</b> the remaining text</a>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="a">
          <xsl:element name="new">
              <xsl:attribute name="attrib1">
                  <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*">
                       <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                       <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<article><new attrib1="&lt;a&gt; &lt;b&gt;a&lt;c&gt;a&lt;/c&gt;aa&lt;/b&gt; the remaining text&lt;/a&gt;"/></article>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964532/xslt-convert-xml-block-under-a-specific-node-to-xml-escaped-content-of-that-node/28964942#28964942 if you are using Saxon.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, following error is there, Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {http://saxon.sf.net/}serialize(), I am using XSLT2 with Saxon 9he.

Comment: With Saxon HE you are out of luck, as the open source version does not have the Saxon extension functions. You can however use Saxon 9.6 HE and `version="3.0"` in your stylesheet, that way you have access to the XPath 3.0 `serialize` function, as also shown in the answer I linked to. As a last resort, you can make use of a serialization implementation done in pure XSLT, also linked to in the comments of the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following XSLT 1.0 stylesheet (also compatible with XSLT 2.0):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:copy>
      <new>
        <xsl:attribute name="attrib1">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </new>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to your input XML:**

```
<article>
      <a>
           <b>a<c>a</c>aa</b> the remaining text</a>
</article>
```

**Yields this output XML:**

```
<article><new attrib1="&lt;a&gt;&lt;b&gt;a&lt;c&gt;a&lt;/c&gt;aa&lt;/b&gt;the remaining text&lt;/a&gt;"/></article>
```

**As requested.**

Comment: @RudramuniTP obviously you'll have to be a lot more creative if any of your XML elements you're trying to serialize could have attributes, or if any of the text could contain `<` or `&` characters (which would need to end up double-escaped like `&amp;lt;` in the final output).

Comment: @IanRoberts, I am agree with your suggestion.